# Plotting a convolution fails

Tags: plotting, convolution

i'm trying to plot a graph of a convolution and a discrete convolution, using *Mathematica* 8

```
x[t_] := exp[-2*t]*(HeavisideTheta[t + 2] - HeavisideTheta[t]) +  
  (1 - t/2)*(HeavisideTheta[t] - HeavisideTheta[t - 2])
y[t_] := -2*DiracDelta[t + 2] +  2*(HeavisideTheta[t] - HeavisideTheta[t - 2])
c[t_] := Convolve[x[d], y[d], d, t]
Plot[c[t], {t, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006]}]
```

This results in an empty graph. Can *Mathematica* 8 plot convolutions?
Same thing happens with discrete convolution.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to write Exp instead of exp

Comment: You could have noticed that exp was undefined by seeing that it is blue. If you notice something like that you can just type it into the search bar of the documentation center.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest doing something like this

```
Clear[x, y, c, d, exp]
x[t_] := Exp[-2*t]*(HeavisideTheta[t + 2] - HeavisideTheta[t]) + (1 - 
     t/2)*(HeavisideTheta[t] - HeavisideTheta[t - 2])
y[t_] := -2*DiracDelta[t + 2] + 
  2*(HeavisideTheta[t] - HeavisideTheta[t - 2])
c[t_] := (c[t] = Convolve[x[d], y[d], d, t]);

kkkk = 4;
arr = Array[c, kkkk*8 + 1, {-4, 4}];
dom = Array[# &, kkkk*8 + 1, {-4, 4}];

ListPlot[Transpose[{dom, arr}], Joined -> True]
```

But note that HeavySideTheta[0] is not defined.

**Remark about the definition of c**

It takes a little while to calculate c. Therefore I used the idiom c[t_]:=c[t]=expr which stores values you have already calculated. Not really necessary as I also store your values in an array, but oh well.

**Better alternative**

You can use the algebraic capabilities to simplify the definition of c first. Then it will no longer take long to calculate values of c. Set

```
Clear[x, y, c, d, c2]
x[t_] := Exp[-2*t]*(HeavisideTheta[t + 2] - HeavisideTheta[t]) + (1 - 
     t/2)*(HeavisideTheta[t] - HeavisideTheta[t - 2])
y[t_] := -2*DiracDelta[t + 2] + 
  2*(HeavisideTheta[t] - HeavisideTheta[t - 2])

(*takes a while*)
c2[t_] := Evaluate[FullSimplify[Convolve[x[d], y[d], d, t]]]
```

Then you can simply do

```
Plot[c2[t], {t, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, Automatic}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006]}]
```

to get your plot.

Comment: Thanks for your time, i really appreciate it.
How long does it take to calculate c? 1,2,15 minutes?
I'm curious about the average time...

Comment: @Nicholas You're welcome. It depends on the argument of c how long it takes. To calculate 9 values of c in the range {-4,4} took about 30 seconds I guess. You can use `Clear[c];AbsoluteTiming[Array[c, kkkk*8 + 1, {-4, 4}]][[1]]` if you want to see how long it took. It also takes less than a minute to complete the (definition using) FullSimplify.